# Brightcove for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am porting an Android application to BlackBerry Storm, running OS 5.0. For playing video, brightcove is used on the Android version. But I can't get any help from brightcove support for BlackBerry.

I am getting an id as the API response, which is used to retrieve the video using brightcove. Please let me know how I can integrate this in my blackberry application.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? I don't see an answerable question here.

Comment: Brightcove doesn't provide any sdk for blackberry (confirmed from the brightcove resources). How can I call brightcove api from blackberry application programatically???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. From the brightcove documentation I got the url for posting the id... Using that I was able to retrieve the video object details including the url..